# Smallipop tooltip on mobile devices hides after beign clicked inside

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, touch

What is wrong with this code?

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/R6Mqe/10/
```

I use Smallipop, and I want to make it visible on mobile.. Settings are here showed:

```
    $('.test').smallipop({
    preferredPosition: 'bottom',
    theme: 'blue',
    hideOnPopupClick: false,
    triggerOnClick:true,  
    hideDelay:10000,
    invertAnimation: true
});
```

And nothing changes if I use it's touchSupport attribute..

Answer (score 1):

this has been fixed in a recent version.
I think you sent me an email a few weeks ago, but maybe someone finds this and needs help too.

Regards,
Sebastian